# UIButton has dot when set to selected inside UIToolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I'm adding a `UIButton` to a `UIToolbar` that I don't want to have as a `UIBarButtonItem` so that I have more control over the position of the `UIButton` inside the frame. I set a different title for both "Normal" and "Selected" states. Everything acts completely normal for a `UIButton` except when it's "Selected" there is a 1 pixel dot in the front of the `UIButton`'s title.

toolbar:

```
    UIToolbar *customView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(HEADER_MARGIN, 0, HEADER_WIDTH, HEADER_HEIGHT)];
[customView setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

button:

```
UIButton *listOrderButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, ORDER_BUTTON_WIDTH, ORDER_BUTTON_HEIGHT)];
[listOrderButton setCenter:CGPointMake(customView.center.x, HEADER_HEIGHT/2)];
[listOrderButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:ORDER_BUTTON_FONT_SIZE]];
[listOrderButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[listOrderButton setTitle:@"ABC" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[listOrderButton setTitle:@"Time" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[listOrderButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueAppColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[listOrderButton addTarget:self action:@selector(listOrderChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[customToolbar addSubview:listOrderButton];
```

and the selector:

```
- (void)listOrderChange:(UIButton *)sender {
[sender setSelected:!sender.selected];
}
```

Image of what's happening:

[image: No dot when not selected] - No dot when not selected
[image: When selected, there's a dot] - When selected, there is a dot

This happens both on the device and in the simulator. Changing the text color for any and all states has no bearing on the color of the dot itself.

I should also point out that the dot is two points wide and one point high.

Comment: Very curious! Is this happening both on the device and in a simulator?

Comment: If you stop in the debugger and `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` do you see anything that doesn't belong in the view hierarchy under your toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using UIButton, I know you dont want to use a UIBarButton, but would it be possible to create a UIBarButton programmatically giving it all the features of a UIButton?
Since UITabBar is like UINavigation Bar and apple suggests using UIBarButtonItem for bar/tabBar Buttons... I believe using a UIBarButtonItem might solve the problem....